# Add facebook permission after initial authorize with iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

How can i add permission after the initial `[facebook authorize:permissions]` with the facebook-ios-sdk?

The main purpose of the app is posting on the facebook wall, but if the user activates an option the app needs more permission and should ask the user again?

But if i try to use the authorize method from the facebook-ios-sdk with different permissions, the sso from facebook says only that this app is already authorized (but the permission stay on that from the first authorization)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not very specific, and thus is difficult to answer. If you're asking for opinions about how you should design the feature to prompt the user on additional permissions, this may not be the best forum for that question. If you are asking a technical question about how to implement that permission change, please update your question to provide more detail on what you're asking for.

Comment: I thought that iOS SDK and a method call shows that im asking how to implement that. I added same words to clarify...

Answer (score 3):

Simply calling `[facebook authorize:permissions]` a second time with a superset array for `permissions` should do the trick.

The second time `authorize:` is called, you'll get a different Facebook SSO screen where only the new permission(s) are shown in the "Using this app requires:" list.

Note: Make sure your second call to `authorize:` is not predicated on `[self.facebook isSessionValid]` returning `false`, because it'll most likely be returning `true`.

**Edit:**

This is the first FB screen I get with no pre-existing permissions and I'm asking for (@"email", @"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"):

[image: first authorizion]

Now, I get this later on when I ask for these permissions (@"email", @"publish_stream", @"publish_actions", **@"user_photos"**):

[image: second authorization]

Comment: Like written above the facebook SSO screen says only that the app is already authorized. Do you have tested this?

Comment: It seems to me that the second call, once basic permissions have been authorized, should say that the permissions are optional, or in addition. But what it looks like is that the new permissions are required to use FB in the app, not just required to do what the user is trying to do at the moment. I thought I saw somewhere where the screen presented actually used the word 'optional' for additional permissions but I have not found that yet.